# how to set a field to be selected by default

Tags: wpf, xaml

hello i dont know how how to set a field to be selected by default
this is my code:

```
<DockPanel>
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="426">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="63"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="79"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Foreground="blue" Margin="0,1,0,4" Height="26">Message Number:</Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Foreground="blue" Margin="0 10 0 0">Title:</Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Foreground="blue" >Message Date:</Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="3" Foreground="blue" Margin="0 10 0 0">Contact Mail:</Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="4" Foreground="blue" Margin="0 10 0 0">Message Type:</Label>
            <Label Grid.Row="5" Foreground="blue" Margin="0 10 0 0">Message Details:</Label>
            <Button Grid.Row="6" Name="saveBtn" Background="White" Margin="6,20,11,36" Width="89" Click="saveBtn_Click">Save</Button>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="IDtbx" Margin="0 10 0 0"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="titletbx" Margin="0 10 0 0"></TextBox>
            <Calendar Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Name="calender"></Calendar>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Name="mailtbx" Margin="0 10 0 0"></TextBox>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Name="typecbx" Margin="0 10 0 0"></ComboBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Name="detailstbx" Margin="0,10,0,1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
        </Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="406">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="372"></RowDefinition>

                    <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="27*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Purple" BorderThickness="3" Margin="18,8,0,7" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="182">
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Name="messageImage" Height="359" Width="177"></Image>
                </Border>
                <Button Name="ChangeImagebtn" Background="white" Content="Change Image" Grid.Row="2" Margin="21,2,0,-2" Click="ChangeImagebtn_Click"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>

    </DockPanel>
```

when i run the program the save button is getting to be selected for some reason and i dont want it to be.
thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the first button is the one that gets selected - but I could well be wrong on that.

You can specify which button you want to be the default by setting the [`IsDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.isdefault.aspx) property of another button to true.

If you want to set the focus to a text box then you can use:

```
FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox}"
```

in the `Window` definition.

[MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.focusedelement.aspx)

Comment: if i got a tab that inside it i got a user control how can i do it ?

Comment: You can do this from XAML - The documentation you refered to gives the example:

<Button Name="btnDefault" IsDefault="true" Click="OnClickDefault">OK</Button>

Comment: yeah but i need to to be set as default on a textBox

Comment: but the problem is that it doesnt have the IsDefault propery unfortunatly